# Creating an html template for an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a web page that should be able to add student courses to a list/grid or whatever kind of html element. I haven't decided what would work best.

I find the courses by using the bootstrap3-typeahead.js and when selecting one of those I want to "add" a "course item" to some sort of basket - like a shopping basket. I have heard that one can use html templates for this, but I can't seem to find any good examples by searching google or in here.

Right now I have loaded a list (1360 items) of objects with attributes:

- course id (ranging from 1-1360)
- course number
- course name
- course teacher
- course keywords

I want this course item to be an overview of the course. I picture something like this:

[image: Picture of how I want to display the courses]

Right now I just use the following to add them as `<li>`elements to a `<ul>` I've made.

```
$("#basket").append('<li>' + item.name + ', ' + item.number + '</li>');
```

Which results in this:
[image: Current view of courses]

I imagined being able to apply the variables to some sort of template which would be done for every single item that was added, e.i. `$("#basket").loadTemplate(<template name>, item.name, item.number etc..)`

## In short:

I want to know if there's some way of using html templates to create elements that I can control with javascript/JQuery and if possible how this is done?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Well now that you ask and looking back at my question it could be quite hard to figure out. I want to know if there's some way of using html templates to create elements that I can control with javascript/JQuery and if possible how this is done?

Comment: You are stating this very broadly :) Yes, you can make a "template" function, but you want the boxes to be dragged? that's a very different question. Maybe splitt your questions in two and leave out the dragging functionality for now

Comment: Look into [handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/), [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/), or [Ember.js](http://emberjs.com/). Any of those should fit your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create a "template" function

```
//example

var myBox = createBox("computer science", "0122", "programming, databases")

$(".myCourseList").append(myBox)

function createBox(courseName, courseId, courseClasses){
    var html = "";
    html += "<div class='courseBox'>" +
        "<p class='courseName'>" + courseName + "</p>" +
        "<p class='courseId'>" + courseId+ "</p>" +
        "<p class='courseClasses'>" + courseClasses + "</p>" +
        "<p class='xOut'>X</p>" +
        "</div>"
    return html;
}
```

Of course you need an entire library for the dragging stuff, but take that as a different task for later.
I've ignored CSS styling, but you would do CSS like normally. just write classes corresponding with those in your code.

Now, when you dynamically create elements, it's important you [delegate](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) your bindings.

```
$(".myCourseList").on("click", "p.xOut", function(){
    $(this).closest(".courseBox").remove(); //edited this line
})
```

Comment: Ahh I found the problem. There's a missing "+" in the first line of the html item..

Comment: I have a weird problem. 

When I try to add the "myBox" inside my "afterSelect" function from my bootstrap3-typeahead I am not able to remove the items anymore. Do you maybe know the reason for this?

Comment: Are your scopes in order? If the variable "myBox" is in a deeper level than the function "createBox" then you can't call createBox() from myBox's location

Comment: That seems to be the problem. How could I go about solving this? Could I move the createBox function inside the afterSelect function?

Comment: Either you do that, or you make sure the function is in the top level (global). That way you don't have to "create" the function every time you call "afterSelect", but that's just nit picking

Comment: Yeah. That could do it as well. Also, when I have more items on the list clicking a single "x" removes them all..?

Comment: That was a typo. I edited my answer. It's the ".coursebox" we want to remove, not ".myCourseList"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110534/discussion-between-zeliax-and-nachodawg).